# Angular - listen on change state of animation elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

Is there a way to listen on a animation key for change of elements that match the state?

For example if we have this elements:

```
<div id="first-div" @fadeInOut></div>
<div id="second-div" @fadeInOut @shaking></div>
<div id="third-div" @shaking></div>
```

I want to listen on which element is currently having `fadeInOut` animation and determine if it's doing `:enter` or `:leave`.

Something like:

```
animations.on('fadeInOut').subscribe((el) => {
  // el will tell us which element is animation and it's having which state.
});
```

Comment: What about animation start and done event, will that help?

Comment: I want to know which element is animation and its animation event name. is that possible with those events? @Chellappanவ

Comment: I am not sure Can you try this solution:https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationEvent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use animation trigger call back to listen animation phases.

**component.html**

```
<div id="first-div" (@fadeInOut.start)="captureStartEvent($event)" @fadeInOut> 
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
captureStartEvent(event: AnimationEvent) {
   
  }
```

[For Reference](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationEvent)